# Could these two of three kittens be premature?

Tags: cats

My cat gave birth to 3 babies. She brought the tabby out of her nest to the house and left the other two (white one and black one). The white and black ones seemed more fragile and looked more underdeveloped compared to the tabby. I'm wondering if anyone could take a peek, as I'm sure they seem premature. Their age is approximately 48 hours.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

They look younger than the other kitten, and this is not unusual in a litter of kittens, as the mating of cats can go on for a couple of days.

The important thing now is to get them food/ Does the mother feed them, and do they get milk from their mother?

If they do not get milk, you will need to hand feed them. You will need to ask your vet for milk and bottles to feed them if they do not get milk from the mother.

Comment: This is good to know. They have all been almost permanently attached since night so I can only assume they are getting milk

Comment: i am glad to hear this,if their bellies look big they get the milk they need.

Comment: If they aren't getting milk (though it sounds like they are!) you'd also have to consult the vet about proper care of neonatal kittens. It's quite involved, which is why most rescues and shelters don't take them (and redirect them to specialists when one is available).

Answer (score -2):

I would call the Vet and ask for the 2 little ones to be seen just to make sure everything is ok. A nursing cat has different nutritional needs than a cat that is not nursing. The momma cat needs more protein, fat, carbs, vitamin's ect so that she and her babies can be healthy. It's important that mom gets good nutrition because that way it can help prevent different illnesses and her babies will be healthy. Make sure momma cat has plenty of fresh water available to her. One thing I would like to add and feel it's very important. Please get momma cat fixed. If your in the US, there are organizations that can help with low cost spay and neutering. I've done a lot of online reading and asking my fur kid's vet questions about cat health, life stages, nutrition and behavior and also people that I trust who have cats. Give momma cat and her babies a gentle hug and kiss for me.

Comment: taking the cat or kittens to the vet now during this critical time of the kittens life is not  good advice.and you do not answer the question about if the kittens are premature.

Comment: Hello Darcy's Mom and welcome to Pets! Please take minute to have a look at the [tour] and [help] to get an understanding of how StackExchange works. Although your advice sounds good, this is not a general discussion forum, but a Q&A site where users post a question and (hopefully) get it answered without the best answer dissappearing in a flood of comments and discussions. That's why we need you to concentrate on the actual question that was asked. Aside from that, thank you for your advice and have a lot of fun.